# Heatmap.js set the default value to be non-zero

Tags: javascript, heatmap

I'm doing some tests with this script [link](https://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/example-legend-tooltip.html), but in my case I would like the basic value not to be zero but a settable value.
In practice I would like to represent the temperature probes of a room, and use the average of the room as the basic value, as it will certainly not be 0.
Does anyone know if it's possible to do this?

Thank you